# SwiftUI NSCursor in DragGesture

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swiftui

I'm working on an app in SwiftUI where I want two views to be resizable by dragging on a divider between them. This is working fine, but the cursor seems to change to `NSCursor.pointingHand`, which is not what I want. In other apps that have features similar to this, it is common to use `NSCursor.resizeLeftRight` for this purpose, but I'm not sure if I can disable the cursor change done by the `DragGesture`. Something like this is a bit weird:

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    ViewA().frame(width: self.width, alignment: .leading)

    Divider().gesture(DragGesture().onChanged({ value in
        self.width = max(150, self.width + value.translation.width)

        NSCursor.resizeLeftRight.push()
    }).onEnded({ _ in
         NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
    })).onHover(perform: {
        [
            true: NSCursor.pointingHand,
            false: NSCursor.resizeLeftRight
        ][$0]!.push()
    })

    ViewB().frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

Is there a way to stop `DragGesture` from modifying the cursor or setting the name of the cursor for it to use, or would I have to write my own drag gesture function here for that?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use `VSplitView`?